# Error with string validation function

Tags: c++, string, validation

Hey im trying to validate a string.  Basically what i want it to do is prevent the user from entering anything other than a string.  Here is my code:

```
**getString**

string getString(string str)
{
    string input;
    do
    {
        cout << str.c_str() << endl;
        cin >> input;
    }
    while(!isalpha(input));
    return input;
}
```

**Errors**

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall Validator::getString(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?getString@Validator@@QAE_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Player::information(void)" (?information@Player@@QAEXXZ)    C:\Users\Conor\Documents\College\DKIT - Year 2 - Repeat\DKIT - Year 2 - Semester 1 - Repeat\Games Programming\MaroonedCA2\MaroonedCA2\Player.obj    MaroonedCA2
Error   3   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Conor\Documents\College\DKIT - Year 2 - Repeat\DKIT - Year 2 - Semester 1 - Repeat\Games Programming\MaroonedCA2\Debug\MaroonedCA2.exe MaroonedCA2
    4   IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "int" exists    c:\Users\Conor\Documents\College\DKIT - Year 2 - Repeat\DKIT - Year 2 - Semester 1 - Repeat\Games Programming\MaroonedCA2\MaroonedCA2\Validator.cpp 72  17  MaroonedCA2
```

**Main**

```
cout << "What is your name ?\n";
    name = validator.getString();<------This skips.

    cout << "\nWhat is your age? ";
    age = validator.getNum();

    string character = "What is your sex M/F?";
    sex = validator.getChar(character);


    cout <<"Name:\n"<< name<<" Age:\n" << age<< " Sex:\n"<< sex <<"\n";
```

**New getString function.**

```
string Validator :: getString()
{
   string input;
    do 
    {
    } 
    while (
    std::find_if_not( 
        std::begin(input), //from beginning
        std::end(input), //to end
        isalpha //check for non-alpha characters
    ) != std::end(input) //continue if non-alpha character is found
);
    return input;
}
```

Comment: You can output a string; you don't have to convert it to a C string first. Anyway, I'm guessing you forgot to prefix it with `Validator::`.

Comment: An integer,double,float etc.....

Comment: `isalpha` takes in a char, not a string

Comment: @BeyondSora, Technically an `int`.

Comment: @chris Yeah i forgot the prefix.  But i still have an error for no suitable conversion. The variable input on the line while(!isalpha(input)); shows this.

Comment: @BeyondSora  is there anything similar for a string.  For example, would this (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),  work with a string.

Comment: @chris thanks for pointing it out. I changed my answer below to say `int` instead now. :-)

Comment: @Pendo826, `while (std::find_if_not(std::begin(input), std::end(input), isalpha) != std::end(input))` should work.

Comment: @chris  Will you answer the post.  With the answer formatted please.

Comment: I got it working i never added  cout << str.c_str() << endl;
        cin >> input; between the while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem described is that this function belongs to a class, but you forgot to specify that:

```
string Validator::getString(string str)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Next, `isalpha` takes an `int` (due to C reasons), and, as far as I know, there is no version for `std::string`. You can, however, use standard algorithms to do this:

```
do {
    ...
} while (
    std::find_if_not( 
        std::begin(input), //from beginning
        std::end(input), //to end
        isalpha //check for non-alpha characters
    ) != std::end(input) //continue if non-alpha character is found
);
```

This `find_if_not` call will search through the string and check if any non-alpha characters are found by comparing the return value to the ending iterator of the string. If they're equal, the string is clean. You might also have to cast `isalpha` because it expects a predicate taking a `char`, not an `int`.

For some samples using this algorithm, see [here](http://ideone.com/XjXWiI). Note that due to the version of GCC on there, `std::begin()` and `std::end()` were replaced, and the `!=` was changed to `==` due to the reversed logic of the function (you'd use it like `do {} while (!ok(...));`).

Comment: Is there an import for the find_if_not ?

Comment: @Pendo826, `find_if_not` also part of C++11, so you'll need the appropriate version of your compiler and argument to use it. Using C++03, I'm pretty sure using `std::find_if` with `std::not1` wrapping `isalpha` would work.

Comment: @chris  im getting a problem.  When i run the code using this cout << "What is your name ?\n";
 name = validator.getString();  It skips the input altogether.

Comment: @Pendo826, Could you post a small, complete sample of code that causes that to happen?

Comment: I have also added the new function you have helped me with.

Answer (score 1):

`isalpha` takes in an int not a string.

One way to make sure every character in your string is a letter would be to do something like this.

```
bool isAlpha = false;
while (!isAlpha) {
// take in input blah blah


    isAlpha = true;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
      if (!isalpha(input[i]))
          isAlpha = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah sorry, should be fixed now.

Comment: Just ran the code with the update.  It skips the string altogether.  This is the way i done it in the main cout << "What is your name ?\n";
 name = validator.getString();

Comment: Yeah i dont quite understand it.

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient method would be to search your string for numeric digits, using the `std::string` functions:

```
static const char digits[] = "0123456789";
isAlpha = text.find_first_of(digits, 0); // start from position 0.
```

Comment: This would return true for anything except finding it at position 0. `isAlpha = text.find_first_of(digits, 0) == std::string::npos;`. I don't know exactly which characters the OP doesn't want, but it would work well if all of those characters are included (or doing a whitelist instead).

Comment: @chris: my understanding is that the 2nd parameter of `find_first_of` is the starting position to search from, inclusive.  Also, the first position in the string is zero.

Comment: Yes, I meant the return value. The only false return possible is if it's found at index 0. Otherwise, the return value will be the index (not 0), or `npos` (also not 0), meaning `isAlpha` will mostly always be true.